Python how to print out the return data?
def calculate_average(numbers):
    total = sum(numbers)
    average = total / len(numbers)
    return average
    
print(average)
calculate_average([34, 30, 12])

Output shows that average is not defined which I dont understand why. Can someone explain why to me? I already know I can use this line print(calculate_average([34, 30, 12])) to print out. But I want to know why my code is not working. I understand return will pass the data outside of the function and end the function, but I dont understand how to print it out as output. Please write down the corrected version and explain me to me. Thank you so much.
I try to use python tutor and also ask chatgpt but still dont understand why or how to make it functioning.

average only exists within the scope of calculate_average. return doesn't return the variable average, it just returns the value of average.

You've defined the function and it will automatically return the average, the scope of average is only inside of the function -it doesn't exist outside of the function unless you explicitly store it to a variable like x = calculate_average([34, 30, 12])

@Loocid even that is the case, how can I out print out the value of average?

you could do average = calculate_average([34, 30, 12]) then print(average). Or just use print(calculate_average([34, 30, 12])) as you've said in your first post.

Your problem is with this line, as the variable average is not defined within global scope:
print(average)

From W3Schools:

A variable is only available from inside the region it is created. This is called scope.


A variable created inside a function belongs to the local scope of that function, and can only be used inside that function.

You are trying to print the variable average from global scope when it was defined in the local scope of your function.
Instead, you could define the variable average in global scope from the return value of your function
average = calculate_average([34, 30, 12])
print(average)

Or just print the function output directly:
print(calculate_average([34, 30, 12]))


The issue with your code is not related to the average variable being undefined, but how you are trying to print the result.
Your function calculate_average correctly calculates the average of a list of numbers and returns the result. In your code, you correctly call this function and store the result in the result variable:
def calculate_average(numbers):
    total = sum(numbers)
    average = total / len(numbers)
    return average
result = calculate_average([34, 30, 12])
print(result)


since your function returns the average value, you can just:
print(calculate_average([34, 30, 12]))

the problem is already answered in the reply section.
or define new average global variable and assign it the value of the function:
average = calculate_average([34, 30, 12])
print(average)

